# LinkedIn API when using timeRange get Error "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER"

Tags: api, timestamp, linkedin-api

Similar to other posts (their solutions didn't help my issue), I am using the LinkedIn V2 API to get company page views and other company analytics as per their documentation.

I've got an approved App, and a token with all of the required scopes: r_organization_social rw_organization_admin

I also ensured I am using the v2 headers as mentioned in other posts:
Headers: Authorization: Bearer XXXXX X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0

When using the v2 endpoints without any timeRange parameters, everything works fine and my get requests retrieve data. As soon as I add their specific timeInterval parameters I get this 403 error (ServiceErrorCode 100):

Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields ####

Where ### the various fields I used (I did various tries with different fields that return similar error).

403 implies Access Denied but my token definitely includes the specific scopes they mention are needed for the Company Pages API.

I tried both the v2 and v1 endpoints seen below, which all return error (where XXXXXX the organization urn):

Endpoint 1 (as per documentation) (error 403):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=MONTH&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1649884565000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1659561365000

Endpoint 2 (without granularity) (error 403):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1649884565000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1659561365000

Endpoint 3 (error 403):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1551398400000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1552003200000

Endpoint 4 (error 400 - invalid query):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1649884565000,end:1659561365000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)

Endpoint 5 (error 400 - invalid query):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1548892800000,end:1558892800000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)

Endpoint 6 (error 400 - invalid query):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1548892800000,end:1558892800000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)

Endpoint 7 (error 400 - invalid query):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange=(start:1548892800000,end:1558892800000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)

Endpoint 8 (only granularity) (error 403):
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY

If I remove all the timeInterval parameters it works fine, but I'm hoping to get historical data with monthly/daily aggregations for our reporting.

I've been struggling with this days on end, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Additional endpoints tried:
Endpoint 9  (only granularity) (error 400 - invalid query):
<https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeGranularityType:MONTH)>

Endpoint 10 (only granularity) (error 403):
<https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=MONTH>

Comment: Additional Endpoints tried: 
Endpoint 11 (only granularity) (error 400 - invalid query):
<https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeGranularityType:MONTH)>

Endpoint 12 (only granularity) (error 403):
<https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&aggregation=MONTH>

Comment: Additional Endpoints tried:                                                                                Endpoint 13 (only granularity) (error 403):
<https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXX&aggregation=MONTH>                       Endpoint 14 (only granularity) (error 403):
<https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:XXXXXX&timeIntervals.aggregation=MONTH>

Answer (score 1):

"Even though I'm using v2 API version and other posts suggested adding the "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" string to the header, for me it eventually worked when I removed this string from the header."

WORKS ALSO FOR ME!!! I think as you pass it in the url, you may need to remove it from the header...

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm using v2 API version and other posts suggested adding the "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" string to the header, for me it eventually worked when I removed this string from the header.